# How to auto change post category with ACF and cron job

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have advanced custom fields installed with some custom fields. I have one custom field to select a date.

Then i want when the date is pased autochange the category.

I have that code:

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'activitats',
                        'post_per_page' => 200,
                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query ($args);
                    if($query->have_posts()){


                        while ($query->have_posts()){

                            $query->the_post();

                            $categorias = get_the_category();

                            if(!in_category(2)){
                                $fecha_activitat = get_field('data', false, false);
                                $fecha_activitat = new DateTime($fecha_activitat);

                                $fecha_activitat = $fecha_activitat->format('d/m/Y');

                                $hoy = new DateTime();
                                $hoy = $hoy->format('d/m/Y');


                                if($fecha_activitat == $hoy){
                                    wp_remove_object_terms($post_id, array(1,2), 'category');
                                    wp_set_post_categories($post_id, 14, true);
                                }elseif($fecha_activitat <= $hoy){
                                    wp_remove_object_terms($post_id, array(14,1), 'category');
                                    wp_set_post_categories($post_id, 2, true);
                                }elseif($fecha_activitat >= $hoy){
                                    wp_remove_object_terms($post_id, array(14,2), 'category');
                                    wp_set_post_categories($post_id, 1, true);
                            }



                            }else{
                            }



                        }


                    }
```

That code worked in the past but now it do not work and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:
Overview
Create a function that sets a WP Cron job to fire the day after an event ends
Create or update that Cron job every time the post is saved (ie. created or edited)
Create a function that puts the post into the past events category
Run that function when the WP Cron job is fire
The code
The code solutions here are very well commented but I have not gone into detail about why I did certain things certain ways due to time. If there is interest in me doing this then please ask in the comments and I will find the time.

Create a function that sets a WP Cron job to fire the day after an event ends.

```
// Create a cron job to run the day after an event happens or ends
function set_expiry_date( $post_id ) {

  // See if an event_end_date or event_date has been entered and if not then end the function
  if( get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = 'event_end_date', $single = true ) ) {

    // Get the end date of the event in unix grenwich mean time
    $acf_end_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = 'event_end_date', $single = true );

  } elseif ( get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = 'event_date', $single = true ) ) {

    // Get the start date of the event in unix grenwich mean time
    $acf_end_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key = 'event_date', $single = true );

  } else {

    // No start or end date. Lets delete any CRON jobs related to this post and end the function.
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'make_past_event', array( $post_id ) );
    return;

  }

  // Convert our date to the correct format
  $unix_acf_end_date = strtotime( $acf_end_date );
  $gmt_end_date = gmdate( 'Ymd', $unix_acf_end_date );
  $unix_gmt_end_date = strtotime( $gmt_end_date );

  // Get the number of seconds in a day
  $delay = 24 * 60 * 60; //24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds

  // Add 1 day to the end date to get the day after the event
  $day_after_event = $unix_gmt_end_date + $delay;

  // Temporarily remove from 'Past Event' category
  wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, 'past-events', 'category' );

  // If a CRON job exists with this post_id them remove it
  wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'make_past_event', array( $post_id ) );
  // Add the new CRON job to run the day after the event with the post_id as an argument
  wp_schedule_single_event( $day_after_event , 'make_past_event', array( $post_id ) );

}
```

Create or update that Cron job every time the post is saved (ie. created or edited)

```
// Hook into the save_post_{post-type} function to create/update the cron job everytime an event is saved.
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'set_expiry_date', 20 );
```

Create a function that puts the post into the past events category

```
// Create a function that adds the post to the past-events category
function set_past_event_category( $post_id ){

  // Set the post category to 'Past Event'
  wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, array( 53 ), true );

}
```

Run that function when the WP Cron job is fire

```
// Hook into the make_past_event CRON job so that the set_past_event_category function runs when the CRON job is fired.
add_action( 'make_past_event', 'set_past_event_category' );
```